# Parts missed when download Amazon webpage with curl

Tags: curl, web-scraping

I have a program that downloads this Amazon webpage: http://www.amazon.com/mobile-apps/b?ie=UTF8&node=2350149011

It then parses it and displays the information to me in a nice format in a small GUI I wrote.
Anyway, this program has worked for months, until today. So after some troubleshooting I figured out that this is because curl isn't downloading the whole webpage anymore. Can anyone tell me why?

Here is the command I used:

```
curl 'http://www.amazon.com/mobile-apps/b?ie=UTF8&node=2350149011' > localpage
```

And here is an image, because a picture is worth a thousand words. Well, that's what they say.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply setting the user agent will fix this issue.
It should look something like this:

```
curl -A "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome" 'http://www.amazon.com/mobile-apps/b?ie=UTF8&node=2350149011' > localpage
```

Hope this helps.